# How to create a fenced field for the drunken walk

Tags: python, random-walk

I bought an Introduction to Python book by John V. Guttag and I am trying to teach myself python. It is going decent for the most part, but I have a question that is not talked about in the book. The latest part talked about the druken walk simulation. In the simulation it uses a field class to create the field for the drunk to walk in. He then creates another kind of field using inheritance. I was wondering what it would take to make a fenced in field that would restrict the drunk from going on the edge and then the drunk having to turn around. Here is the field code:

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.drunks = {}

    def addDrunk(self, drunk, loc):
        if drunk in self.drunks:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate drunk')
        else:
            self.drunks[drunk] = loc

    def moveDrunk(self, drunk):
        if drunk not in self.drunks:
            raise ValueError('Drunk not in field')
        xDist, yDist = drunk.takeStep()
        currentLocation = self.drunks[drunk]
        #use move method of Location to get new location
        self.drunks[drunk] = currentLocation.move(xDist, yDist)

    def getLoc(self, drunk):
        if drunk not in self.drunks:
            raise ValueError('Drunk not in field')
        return self.drunks[drunk]
```

and here is the other field he made using inheritance:

```
class oddField(Field):
    def __init__(self, numHoles, xRange, yRange):
        Field.__init__(self)
        self.wormholes = {}
        for w in range(numHoles):
            x = random.randint(-xRange, xRange)
            y = random.randint(-yRange, yRange)
            newX = random.randint(-xRange, xRange)
            newY = random.randint(-yRange, yRange)
            newLoc = Location(newX, newY)
            self.wormholes[(x, y)] = newLoc

    def moveDrunk(self, drunk):
        Field.moveDrunk(self, drunk)
        x = self.drunks[drunk].getX()
        y = self.drunks[drunk].getY()
        if (x, y) in self.wormholes:
            self.drunks[drunk] = self.wormholes[(x, y)]
```

The odd field uses wormwholes to move the drunk which is pretty cool. I am still new to python so I am curious how this would work.

Comment: Could you be more precise with your question, what exactly are you curious about is it the `moveDrunk` method in the subclass `oddField` that you are curious about?

Comment: Is it really so hard to indent the code correctly? I would fix it for you but the last time I did something like that my edit was rejected and I can understand why, I can't be really sure what your intent was.

Comment: Yea I am sorry about that. I did not realize that it was not indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply override the logic of the moveDrunk() method, such that the drunk remains within the fence if the coordinates are outside of your desired Cartesian space, and also override the initialization to provide that restricted Cartesian space. Consider the following pseudocode:

`class stephenDaedalus(Field):`

def **init**(self, cartesianSpace):
   Field.init(self)
   self.fence = cartesianSpace
   ...
def moveDrunk(self):
    '''Note where our drunk is located, as he may do something impossible'''
    lastX = self.drunks[drunk].getX()
    lastY = self.drunks[drunk].getY()
    Field.moveDrunk(self, drunk)
    x = self.drunks[drunk].getX()
    y = self.drunks[drunk].getY()
    '''check that our drunk is still within parameters'''
    if (x, y) in self.cartesianSpace.points:
        self.drunks[drunk] = currentLocation.move(x, y)
    '''and if he is not, he will stumble back to the old manifold'''
    else:
        self.drunks[drunk] = currentLocation.move(lastX, lastY)

You'll have to implement a CartesianField class, but if you think about this mathematically, you'd like to accept maybe a list of points and then fill another list with the integer points within the field delimited by the list. An interesting challenge for the new programmer. Consider using Python's rectangle class to save yourself the Euclidean headache:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PointsAndRectangles

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is about how the method `moveDrunk` in the `OddField` subclass works.

A subclass extends its superclass (this applies to most if not all OO languages) the `OddField` class here extends the Field class in that it adds a property called `wormholes`, and also overrides the superclass' `moveDrunk` method meaning it gives it a new implementation.

The subclass now has all the members of its superclass but with one new property and also a more customised implementation of `moveDrunk` that is more relevant to the subclass.

So we know the subclass `OddField` can act like a normal field but it has extra behaviour that comes from the implementation of `OddField`. So if we call the `moveDrunk` method on our `OddField` it will implement the new behaviour instead of the behaviour in our superclass.

But, if your question is about how wormholes work, I'm sorry but i can't help you there. ;)